# How can I resolve "LateInitializationError: Field 'userMap' has not been initialized."

Tags: java, flutter, dart, widget

```
late Map<String,dynamic> userMap;

bool isLoading = false;
final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();


void onSearch() async{
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
});
await _firestore.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: _search.text)
    .get().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userMap = value.docs[0].data();
        isLoading = false;
      });
      print(userMap);
});

}
```

This first part of the code work proprely but when I want to create my ListTile the error pop up.

```
userMap != null ?
        ListTile(
          title: Text(userMap['name']),
          subtitle: Text(userMap['email']),
        ):Container(),
```

If somoene can help me that's will be great thank you !

Comment: Just do this
late Map<String,dynamic> userMap ={}; or remove late from keyword and check usermap.isEmpty()

Comment: If you can't guarantee that a variable will be initialized before it's accessed, *don't use `late`*!  It makes no sense to make a variable `late` *and* to check if it's `null`.  If you need to check if it's `null`, then make it nullable.  Alternatively make it non-nullable and initialize it to a non-null value at the beginning.

Comment: I try to remove the Late but I can't an error pop again

Comment: just try `Map<String,dynamic>? userMap;` instead of `late Map<String,dynamic> userMap;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `late` keyword can be used when you have a non-nullable variable, but you just want to initialize it later. The variable will never be null, having only two states, non initialized or initialized with a non-null value.

If you want to work with nullable variables you can only add the `?` keyword to the variable like `Map<String,dynamic>? userMap;`

Comment: thanks It's work now I just add a null check on the scnd part after do that thanks you very much

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<String, dynamic> userMap = <String, dynamic>{};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).